# Windows TASKKILL syntax issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, taskkill

After all these years, you'd think I had done some Windows batch files of some type. But you'd be wrong. I am updating a batch file and encountered the following statement:

```
TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq SIM RH*" /IM perl.exe
```

Why both the /FI and the /IM? Are the two clauses anded together? If I leave off the /IM, the correct processes get killed.

The only way this makes sense is if they get ended and kill only tasks with that window title AND are perl.exe tasks.

Comment: `/FI` is a filter according to `taskkill /?` so this was supposed to be killing only the perl.exe window with the title `SIM RH` I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are added!

`/IM` would be killing **all** tasks with different process-IDs
`/FI` applies a filter to that. You can test that with something like this:

```
@echo off
for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do start "%%i" cmd.exe
timeout /t 3
taskkill /F /FI "WindowName ne 3" /IM cmd.exe
```

This should leave you with 1 command-prompt with the title 3. All others will be closed.

Changing the `ne` to `eq` would only close the command-prompt with the title `3` leaving you with `1, 2, 4, 5` and `yourBatch.bat`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The given `/FI "WINDOWTITLE eq SIM RH*"` option will filter processes by window title starting with `SIM RH`. The [reference for `taskkill`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725602(v=ws.11).aspx) specifies that if such a filter is given, the wildcard character `*` is accepted for the `/IM` option.

*What isn't being said is the fact that adding a filter and leaving out the `/IM` seems to imply `/IM *`.*

You can verify this behaviour with following command, which will open a regular shell and a powershell in two separate windows, and then kill both windows just by specifying a window title filter.

```
start "testp1" cmd && start "testp2" powershell && taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq testp*"
```